# Get all singletons that inherit a class via reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have the following scenario:

```
class Cow : Animal
{
   public int animalID;
   private static Cow instance;
   public static Cow Instance
   {
      get 
      {  
          if (instance == null) instance = new Cow();
          return instance;     
      }
    }
   private Cow() { }
}
```

`Cow` is an ordinary singleton that inherit from `Animal`.
What I need: a `Dictionary<int, Animal>` with all singletons that inherit from type `Animal`, such that, a) the list is first filled with all existing singletons [already been instantiated], and b) a method that add to my dictionary items not already been instantiated.

For implemented classes Cow, Goat and Zebra I want that behavior:

```
public class Cow : Animal { ... }
public class Goat : Animal { ... }
public class Zebra : Animal { ... }

public static class AnimalManagement
{
   static Dictionary<int, Animal> zoo = new Dictionary<int, Animal>();
   static void FillDictionary();
   static Animal GetAnimalID(int animalID);    
}

public Main()
{
   var a1 = Cow.Instance;
   var a2 = Goat.Instance;

   AnimalManagement.FillDictionary();
   // Now, zoo.Count() == 2

   // Suppose I seeking for Zebra, with animalID  == 5:
   Animal zebra = AnimalManagement.GetAnimalID(5);
   // Thus, zoo.Count() == 3 and zeebra singleton was 
   // instantiated and added to internal dic of AnimalManagement.
}
```

So I want to fill the dictionary at running time by reflection.
Is it possible my friends?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want/need singletons per class type?

Comment: Unfortunately is the class model that we are working with. Can't be changed at this time.

Comment: Is it possible to add this dictionary to the base class `Animal`, sync it when creating a singleton (from the derived class) and then expose it?

Comment: Need some clarification before answering. How  you are assigining Id to animal? is it constant animal identifier or something which can be changed

Comment: Nice observation! But from OO point of view, don't make much sense for me Animal keep information about AnimalManagement, the inverse sounds great. Thanks for answering, I'll take it into account!

Comment: animalID is a constant. My mistake not include it in description.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially:

```
var types = myAssembly.GetTypes(t => typeof(Animal).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsAbstract);
var instances = types.Select(t => t.GetProperty("Instance", B.Static).GetValue(null, null));
```

Comment: Almost there my friend, one of my big problems here is that the singleton itself may have the exact name "Instance". It may vary, since I didn't imposed any restriction to it, in accordance with my OO model.

Comment: And that's yet another instance singletons are dumb. In some places we have "Current" and "CurrentDomain" and "Instance" and other crap. Somewhere you have to specify something. The languages have support for polymorphism through Interfaces and virtual keywords. Use those features and get a real IoC container for your instances. There are plenty of great C# IoC containers.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can, reflection is typically slow, and even slower when you're doing assembly searching.  Could you use meta data (some DSL like XML) to achieve this configuration you're looking for?

If you still want reflection, it will boil down to these steps (pseudo-code):

- Get your executing assembly
- Get the module from your assembly
- Get the types from the module where type.BaseType == typeof(Animal)
- Once you have these types, you'll need to create them. You can Invoke the `Instance` method on the type *or* if you remove the singleton part, you can create the type using Activator ([activator API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx)). Either way, you get your `Animal`.